# Ubuntu 16.10 doesn't support 3 monitors

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, 16.10, nvidia-geforce

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.10 and the Nvidia drivers for my GTX 970.

I've been able to get the system running with 2 displays (all combinations of DVI/HDMI/Display port) however when I plug my third monitor into the system the graphics system seems to stop responding until I unplug the 3rd monitor. Sometimes the system completely bricks.

My specs are:

- AMD FX8320
- 16GB Corsair Ram
- EVGA GTX 970SC

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe try installing the drivers for your card as explained in this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Nitpicking on the definition of the word `brick`: Once a smartphone, tablet, router, etc is so seriously misconfigured that it can't be revived it has the technological value of a brick. Thus it is [`bricked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_(electronics)). IMHO your system isn't exactly bricked .